# running through array from form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I made a basic fixture generator, which also generates input fields for each team's score to be entered. The goal is to then have these scores update a league table.

I am nearly there, but am stuck on one part. Note: the code below deliberately won't update a league table or send the scores any further for the time being, as I just wanted to test the output first to make sure it was working.

I submit the scores on the fixtures page and once I submit, I have a loop that is supposed to cycle through each row (eg Team 1-12, Team 2 -15) and work out the winner. Now here is where the problem lies - my loop only returns the final row scores and works out the winner, then repeats (team 2 are winner) 19 times (there are 19 rows of fixtures.

What I can't work out is whether my data is being overwritten on each iteration of the loop, or possibly (and I think this is more likely) it is only ever taking the final row into consideration as the data is not in the correct array format to be able to loop through.

Here is some code. Note $teams is an array from a previous page form input (user types team names, and this following code produces a list of fixtures, with boxes to enter scores);

```
$counter=0;

foreach ($teams as $team) {


  foreach ($teams as $opposition) {

    if ($team != $opposition) {

    $str = <<<EOF
    <input type="hidden" name="team1" value="$team[1]">
    <input type="hidden" name="team2" value="$opposition[1]">
    <tr><td>Row $counter<input type="hidden" value="$counter" name="row1"><td><input          type="hidden" name="team_id" class="invis" value="$team[0]"><td><input type="text"     name="team1_score"> $team[1] 
        <td>  versus  <td> <input type="hidden" value="$opposition[0]"><td> $opposition[1]  <td><input type="text" name="team2_score"><td>Row $counter<input type="hidden" value="$counter"    name="row2"></tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="fixtures" value="$counter">

EOF;

      echo $str;
      $counter++;

      }
      }
}

echo "<hr><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Go\">";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
```

And now the code I am having the problem with, it outputs the scores for the final row ONCE, then outputs the draw/win/lose statements 19 times (number of fixtures)...

```
$team1=$_POST['team1'];
$team2=$_POST['team2'];
$row1=$_POST['row1'];
$row2=$_POST['row2'];
$fixtures=$_POST['fixtures'];
$team_id=$_POST['team_id'];
$team1_score=$_POST['team1_score'];
$team2_score=$_POST['team2_score'];
$games=$_POST['games'];


$games=array('TeamOne: ' =>$team1, 'Goals: '=> $team1_score, 'TeamTwo: ' => $team2, 'Goals2:      '=>$team2_score);
$row=0;
while ($row<$fixtures) {
foreach ($games as $key=>$value) {
 echo "$key  $value  <br>";
} 


if ($team1_score > $team2_score) {
  echo "$team1 are the winners";
  $row++;
}
else if ($team2_score > $team1_score) {
  echo "$team2 are the winners";
  $row++;
}
else {
echo "Drawed";
$row++;
}
}
```

So this outputs the teams and scores for the final fixture on the page before, then (depending on the score) repeats the winners or draw options 19 times.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing 19 times the same attribute name in the same form, so you will receive only one element. Try to change your inputs for arrays and then you will receive an array of elements that you can iterate normally in PHP.

```
    $counter=0;

    foreach ($teams as $team) {


      foreach ($teams as $opposition) {

        if ($team != $opposition) {

        $str = <<<EOF
        <input type="hidden" name="team1[]" value="$team[1]"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="team2[]" value="$opposition[1]"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="team1_score[]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="team2_score[]" />

// etc...

    EOF;

          echo $str;
          $counter++;

          }
          }
    }

    echo "<hr><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Go\">";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</table>";
```